# No gcm for subsequent messages in conversation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, intercom

I'm using intercom.io to send messages to my customers. I can receive gcm (with notification) from intercom just fine, ONLY if the message that I sent is the first message in a conversation. For subsequent messages in the conversation, I don't receive anything. I put a log in my onMessageReceived() but it didn't receive anything, except if the message is the first message in a conversation.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {    

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        MessageUtils.log("onMessageReceived data is " + data);
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I missing?

In case you don't get what I'm trying to say, here's what I meant:

1. I select a customer from my intercom.io web dashboard (or
   whatever it's called)
2. Then I click on the 'Message' button to
   send a message to the customer.
3. The customer received my message, together with the notification.
4. Now I send another message to the customer within the same conversation as before.. but now the customer won't receive any more gcm message from intercom.

Comment: I'm not familiar with intercom, however if you are using GCM now (FCM) and Android, maybe you should give Firebase Cloud Messaging a try. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does support now. The [github issue](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/issues/228) is closed now and they added it in 3.0.3

They have a [git hub project](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/tree/master/samples/intercom-sample-fcm) for FCM, but it is missing few code.
The code is available on [this github page](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/issues/249) and is as follows

if you are extending FirebaseMessagingService in a class in your own app? then you will need to manually pass on the push to intercom now.

```
private final IntercomPushClient intercomPushClient = new IntercomPushClient();
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      Map<String, String> message = remoteMessage.getData();
      if (intercomPushClient.isIntercomPush(message)) {
          intercomPushClient.handlePush(getApplication(), message);
      } else {
          //DO HOST LOGIC HERE
     }
 }
```